# Android: how to store an Object in consecutive Service calls?

Tags: android, service, remoteview, storing-data

I call a `Service` several times, the Service performs its job and then stop himself.

What I need is to store an abject between consecutive calls of the same Service,

So that:

- every time the Service is called it retrieves the object uses
- and it saves it again before stopping for using it in the next call.

The object in question is a `RemoteViews` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use can use Singleton Pattern:

```
public class SingletonClass{
   private YourObject objectToStoreBetweenSession;
   private SigletonClass instance;
   private SingletonClass(){
       objectToStoreBetweenSession = new YourObject();
   }

   private static SingletonClass getInstance(){
      if(instance==null)
         instance = new SingletonClass();
      return instance;
   }
   public void setObject(YourObject obj){
      objectToStoreBetweenSession = obj;
   }
   public YourObject getObject(){
      return objectToStoreBetweenSession;
   }
}
```

Into your `Service`:

```
YourObject objectToStoreBetweenSession = SingletonClass.getInstance().getObject();
if(objectToStoreBetweenSession.value==0){
   //First time that Service is called.
}else{
   //Do whatever you want
   SingoletonClass.getInstance().setObject(new YourObject("value"));
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, that is what I need. Please can I ask you a favor? Could you fine fix your code because Eclipse gives me errors. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Eclipse doesn't know YourObject object. You have to change it with your RemoteViews initializating it in SingletonClass private constructor with your parameters.